# Nginx timeout for websocket

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, websocket, timeout, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm connecting a client with websocket through Nginx (as a reverse proxy) to an asp.net core application. Between server and client there are heartbeat commands to keep websocket connection open.

My Problem is when a client disconnects by unplugging the network cable the connection remains open. I would like to set a timeout that when the client doesn't send anything for a certain time that the connection gets closed.

I tried multiple timeouts without any effect. (`proxy_send_timeout`, `client_body_timeout`, `keepalive_timeout`, `send_timeout`...) The only timeout I managed to set was `proxy_read_timeout`. What I didn't like was that this timeout was reset every time the server send anything (and not the client).

Which timeout do I have to set to disconnect the client if the client doesn't send anything for *x* seconds?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Not really. One possibility is to implement it on application layer. Other possibility would be setting tcp timeouts on operatingsystem level.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this configuration?

```
 location /ws {
                proxy_read_timeout 300s;
                proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
            proxy_pass https://your_channel_daphne;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
```

I tried that and resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I gave it a try and the connection still took ~15min to time out. I guess this is some TCP timeout from the operating system. Instead I would like to reduce it to 1-2 mins.